# How to refresh a webpage when disconnected from a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I have been watching videos on a video site recently. But unfortunately, the network connection is very bad, it will be disconnected from the video streaming website in a few minutes, and the webpage cannot be reconnected automatically.

For example, I am currently visiting the video site a.com, where the video streaming transmission address is b.com, and now due to some network failure, I disconnected the link with b.com, sulting in the video not playing properly.

So I sought a solution that would automatically refresh the webpage after disconnecting from the video streaming website. How should i do it

Thank you

Comment: Is the video site dropping/having issues, or is your network connection to all sites cutting out?

Comment: @Nisala Only the connection to the video streaming server failed, and other websites accessed normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad / ambiguous. Try to give more details about the page and exact situation.

However, in a broad sense I can answer that you may be interested in checking the JavaScript [ononline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/ononline) and [onoffline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onoffline) events, which in modern browsers can allow you to detect changes in the network online status. However, be aware these events can give false positives in some machines.

Comment: Sorry, I have added more details now